# Form framework for dynaimcally adding, altering fields

Tags: php, javascript

I have several forms on my website in which fields are dynamically created or altered based on what is altered in previous fields?  Is there a good framework for doing this easily?

Answer (score 1):

[Kohana](http://www.kohanaphp.com/) offers an Object Oriented approach to form generation and validation with their [Formo module](http://dev.kohanaphp.com/projects/formo). The official Formo documentation can be found online at http://www.avanthill.com/formo_manual/

The compliment this server-side logic, [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) (Javascript Framework) comes with a great [Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) that is in wide-spread use all over the web. It too has a very simple and straight forward application.

Comment: @Jonathon, is there a jQuery plugin for creation/altering fields dynamically?  Validation is not a big issue on the page, but we have a pretty complicated logic tree which field will appear next.

Comment: Brian, there are many plugins (http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Plugins/category/20) but without knowing more about what your specific needs are, I can't make any specific suggestions.

Comment: I have form that starts with one set of select boxes, when a select box changes, the values in the select boxes are used to populate a table of radio buttons.  Once a radio button is selected some more select boxes appear.  When a complete set of data is selected, the form is submitted to an iframe and the inputs are processed.  I have the logic for populating the inputs coded in PHP, all the JavaScript to make inputs appear and gets tedious.